# Substring the line from specific char to specific char

Tags: c#

I have a string like this "4 Program Files (x86) 2" .
4 is line ID , and 2 is parent ID , the text between is the content .
How can i extract each from the given string so i can create object with properties ID ,content and ParentID ?

Comment: Are the lineId-content-Id always separated by spaces? If so you could `.Split` the string and the first item in the array will be the line ID and the last in the array the ID and all items in between make up the content. This is a very 'basic' way of doing it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Comment: Okey , didn't know the policy sorry .

Comment: Yes they are , i will use .Split i was trying with Substring or Trim , coudln't do it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string methods like `IndexOf/LastIndexOf` or `Substring`:

```
int firstSpaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
int lastSpaceIndex = input.LastIndexOf(' ');
 // check that firstSpaceIndex != lastSpaceIndex and both are >= 0 because that would be invalid

string id = input.Remove(firstSpaceIndex);
string content = input.Substring(firstSpaceIndex + 1, lastSpaceIndex - firstSpaceIndex).Trim();
string parentId = input.Substring(lastSpaceIndex).Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

**String.ToCharArray Method ()**

[document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx)

example :

```
string myString =new string();

char[] strChars=myString.ToCharArray();

char lineID=strChars[0];

char parentID=strChars[strChars.length-1];

char[] content=new char[strChars.length-2];

Buffer.BlockCopy(content,0,strChars,1,strchars.length-1);

string strContent =new string(content);
```

Comment: Why he should use `ToCharArray`? Sorry, didn't get it.

Comment: Maybe i will understand this answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter okay let's show you some more information :))

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `String.Split()`, a `List<String>`, and `String.Join()`:

```
string data = "4 Program Files (x86) 2";

string LineID = "";
string ParentID = "";
string Content = "";
List<string> values = new List<string>(data.Split(' '));
if (values.Count >= 3)
{
    LineID = values[0];
    ParentID = values[values.Count - 1];
    values.RemoveAt(0);
    values.RemoveAt(values.Count - 1);
    Content = String.Join(" ", values.ToArray());
}

Console.WriteLine("LineID = " + LineID);
Console.WriteLine("ParentID = " + ParentID);
Console.WriteLine("Content = " + Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions. In your case it would be something like this:

```
string regex = "(?![0-9])(.*)(?=[0-9])";
string toSplit = "4 Program Files (x86) 2";
string [] result = Regex.Split(toSplit, regex);
foreach (string s in result)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The second string in array is your result. Reference System.Text.RegularExpressions; in your class.

Comment: i think it does not need this complexity

Comment: In my solution, the text can vary between the 2 numbers. Dont know why it is downvoted.

Comment: all he need just getting chars .that's enough. your solution is good where you are looking something in the string

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses Substring(), but it assumes you know the length of parent_ID and line_ID before hand (1 in the following code)...

```
    string mystr = "4 Program Files (x86) 2";
    mystr = mystr.Substring(1, mystr.Length - 2);
    Console.WriteLine(mystr);// Program Files (x86) 

    mystr = "4 Program Files (x86) 2";
    mystr = mystr.Substring(0, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(mystr);//print 4

    mystr = "4 Program Files (x86) 2";
    mystr = mystr.Substring( mystr.Length-1, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(mystr);//print 2
```

Comment: This is a correct way of doing it but it doesn't take bigger numbers into account (don't think it deserves a downvote for that tho)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
        var str = "4 Program Files (x86) 2";
        var splitted = str.Split(' '); // splits the string
        var id = splitted[0]; // the first position of the array is the id
        var parentId = splitted[splitted.Length - 1]; // the last position of the array is the parentId

        var content = str.Substring(id.Length, str.Length - id.Length - parentId.Length); // gets the content between the id and parentId
```